# JavaScript String indexOf() selects also 1&3 instead of only 13

Tags: javascript, indexof

I have this `indexOf()`, the issue I have is that when `norms[]` has an dataset like `2,13` that options that are set as `selected` in `norm_id['+nr+'][]` are not only the values `2` and `13` but also the values `1` and `3`

```
var element = document.getElementById('norm_id['+nr+'][]');
var values = norms[];
for (var i = 0; i < element.options.length; i++) {
   element.options[i].selected = values.indexOf(element.options[i].value) >= 0;
}
```

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: can u paste the actual value of element? it isn't reflected this way

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: So sounds like you need a regular expression instead of indexOf. Code has no clue that you want to match exactly 1. Not 13.

Comment: Split the values/options on `,` and treat them correctly as list of elements

Comment: What is the `norms[]`  construct? If it is `[2,13]` then Array.indexOf(1) will not find 13 If it is a string then yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue with the code below.

```
var element = document.getElementById('calc_norm_id['+nr+'][]');
var values = norms;
var values_split = values.split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < element.options.length; i++)
{
   for(var j = 0; j < values_split.length; j++)
   {
       if(element.options[i].value == values_split[j])
       {
           element.options[i].selected = element.options[i].value;
       }
   }
}
```

@Andreas thx for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your own answer,

```
element.options[i].selected = element.options[i].value
```

does not look right to me - You likely mean

```
element.options[i].selected = true;
```

which translates the whole `if` into

```
element.options[i].selected element.options[i].value == values_split[j];
```

This is simpler

```js
const norms = "1,13";
const nr = 1;
var values_split = norms.split(',');

var options = document.getElementById('calc_norm_id[' + nr + '][]').options;
[...options].forEach(opt => opt.selected = values_split.indexOf(opt.value) != -1);
```

```html
<select id="calc_norm_id[1][]" multiple>
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thx for your post, I will check in my code.